# Dealing with huge (potentially over 30000x30000) images in Python?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to use a python script called deepzoom.py to convert large overhead renders (often over 1GP) to the Deep Zoom image format (ie, google maps-esque tile format), but unfortunately it's powered by PIL, which usually ends up crashing due to memory limitations. The creator has said he's delving into VIPS, but even nip2 (the GUI frontend for VIPS) fails to open the image. In another question by someone else (though on the same topic), someone suggested [OpenImageIO](http://openimageio.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page), which looks like it has the ability, and has Python wrappers, but there aren't any proper binaries provided, and trying to compile it on Windows is a nightmare.

Are there any alternative libraries for Python I can use? I've tried PythonMagickWand (wrapper for ImageMagick) and PythonMagick (wrapper for GraphicsMagick), but both of those also run into memory problems.

Comment: What's stopping you from using Linux for OpenImageIO? Get a small external hard drive and install it up (or an unused internal drive). I also trust your system spec is up to the task. You can try splitting it up into smaller images and converting those as well

Comment: I had tried that earlier, with unsuccessful results, though I hadn't done much to set it up correctly. Maybe this sounds ridiculous, but I assumed it wouldn't be compatible if I tried to run the script on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

I had a very similar problem and I ended up solving it by using netpbm, which works fine on windows.  Netpbm had no problem with converting huge .png files and then slicing, cropping, re-combining (using pamcrop, pamdice, and pamundice) and converting back to .png without using much memory at all.  I just included the necessary netpbm binaries and dlls with my application and called them from python.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're trying to use georeferenced imagery or something similar, for which a GIS solution sounds more appropriate.  I'd use [GDAL](http://gdal.org/) -- it's an excellent library and comes with easy-to-use Python bindings via Swig.

On Windows, the easiest way to install it is via Frank Warmerdam's [FWTools](http://fwtools.maptools.org/) package.

Comment: That's perfect. Even seems to incorporate pyramid creation tools, too, which is a plus. Cheers!

Comment: Hmm, apparently not. GDAL relies on libjpeg, which returns 'Insufficient memory' when trying to open the image. Perhaps I need to (somehow) convert it to a raw format before I can do anything with it. I'll attempt to compile on a linux VM, and see how it goes.

Comment: @Nicolas: Hmm... I know that GDAL is capable of working with images too large to fit in memory.  I haven't used the JPEG driver extensively, so I can't comment on it, but I would expect you would have better success with a raw format.

Comment: Could you maybe chunk the images out in a non-python preprocessor. Break them up into, asy, 1k x 1k tiles?

Answer (score 2):

I'm able to use [pyvips](https://pypi.org/project/pyvips/) to read images with size (50000, 50000, 3):

```
img = pyvips.Image.new_from_file('xxx.jpg')
arr = np.ndarray(buffer=img.write_to_memory(),
                  dtype=np.uint8,
                  shape=[img.height, img.width, img.bands])
```

Answer (score 0):

Is a partial load useful? If you use PIL and the image format is .BMP: you can open() an image file (which doesn't load it), then do a crop(), and then load - which will only actually load the part of the image which you've selected by crop. Will probably also work with TGA, maybe even for JPG and less efficiently for PNG and other formats.

Answer (score 0):

[libvips](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/) comes with a very fast DeepZoom creator that can work with images of any size. Try:

```
$ vips dzsave huge.tif mydz
```

Will write the tiles to `mydz_files` and also write a `mydz.dzi` info file for you. It's typically 10x faster than `deepzoom.py` and has no size limit.

See [this chapter in the manual](http://libvips.github.io/libvips/API/current/Making-image-pyramids.md.html) for an introduction to `dzsave`.

You can do the same thing from Python using [pyvips](https://pypi.org/project/pyvips/) like this:

```py
import pyvips

my_image = pyvips.Image.new_from_file("huge.tif", access="sequential")
my_image.dzsave("mydz")
```

The `access="sequential"` tells pyvips it can stream the image rather than having to read the whole thing into memory.